# Focusing on a Div Element - React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'd like to have an onKeyPress event triggered when a key is pressed when a 'Level' is displaying.
From what I've read, a div needs to be focused on in order for them to register - But I'm not quite sure how to achieve this using functional components.

```
const handleKeyPress = e => {
    console.log(e);
}

export default () => {
    const [currentLevel, setCurrentLevel] = useState(1);

    return (
        <Level onKeyPress={handleKeyPress} />
    )
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is going wrong? What is a `<Level>`, anyway? Indeed a key press is only triggered when focus is on an element that triggers key press (or, also, I think on the document).

Comment: @minitauros <Level /> is a component with a single <div> </div> in the render method.

Comment: So then yes, as @Lekoaf says below, a `<div>` element typically doesn't register key presses. You can register an event listener on the `document` instead. Then during that event you'll have to find the `<Level>` div, but that doesn't sound like it should be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding eventlisteners in a useEffect?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const myFunc = () => {}

    document.addEventListener('keyPress', myFunc)

    return () => {
        document.removeEventListener('keyPress', myFunc)
    }
}, [])
```